# Grab intent information from a service, only once

Tags: android, android-intent, service, oncreate

I am running a service. My ideal process would be to call a method once, get the intent/extras and set parameters, then run my service for a given amount of time.

From my understanding, onCreate() is called only once, while onStartCommand is called every time your service is called. This currently puts me in a backward situation, the method I want called once, doesn't have access to the intent extras, and I don't want to reassign parameters each time the startService is called through the method that has intent access (or should I not care about this happening?).

Is the only way to go about getting what I want to happen the way I want it, to just restrict the ability to start the service if it is already running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

put a static int flag in onCreate and raise it to 1 on first call then check it in OnStartcommand whether this flag is 1 or zero if zero do what ever u want to do else do nothing

```
  static int flag=0;
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    flag=1
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if(flag==0){
//run ur code
}
}
```